# Why is this bit-hack code portable?

Tags: c

```
int v;
int sign; // the sign of v ;
sign = -(int)((unsigned int)((int)v) >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1));
```

**Q1:** Since v in defined by type of `int` ,so why bother to cast it into `int` again? Is it related to portability?

**Edit:**

**Q2:**

```
sign = v >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1);
```

this snippt  **isn't** portable, since **right** shift of `signed int` is **implementation defined**, how to pad the left margin bits is up to complier.So

```
 -(int)((unsigned int)((int)v)
```

do the poratable trick. Explain me why thid works please.
Isn't **right shift** of `unsigned int` alway padding **0** in the left margin bits ?

Comment: I guess you mean this bit in the expression: `(int)v`?

Comment: Are you referring to the overall casting in "int" or just the ((int)v) casting of v?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg , I did mean it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be quite portable because when you convert `int` to `unsigned int` (via a cast), you receive a value that is 2's complement bit representation of the value of the original `int`, with the most significant bit being the sign bit.

**UPDATE**: A more detailed explanation...

I'm assuming there are no padding bits in `int` and `unsigned int` and all bits in the two types are utilized to represent integer values. It's a reasonable assumption for the modern hardware. Padding bits are a thing of the past, from where we're still carrying them around in the current and recent C standards for the purpose of backward compatibility (i.e. to be able to run code on old machines).

With that assumption, if `int` and `unsigned int` have `N` bits in them (`N` = `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)`), then per the C standard we have 3 options to represent `int`, which is a signed type:

1. sign-and-magnitude representation, allowing values from -(2<sup>N-1</sup>-1) to 2<sup>N-1</sup>-1
2. one's complement representation, also allowing values from -(2<sup>N-1</sup>-1) to 2<sup>N-1</sup>-1
3. two's complement representation, allowing values from -2<sup>N-1</sup> to 2<sup>N-1</sup>-1 or, possibly, from -(2<sup>N-1</sup>-1) to 2<sup>N-1</sup>-1

The sign-and-magnitude and one's complement representations are also a thing of the past, but let's not throw them out just yet.

When we convert `int` to `unsigned int`, the rule is that a non-negative value `v` (>=0) doesn't change, while a negative value `v` (<0) changes to the positive value of 2<sup>N</sup>+`v`, hence `(unsigned int)-1`=`UINT_MAX`.

Therefore, `(unsigned int)v` for a non-negative `v` will always be in the range from 0 to 2<sup>N-1</sup>-1 and the most significant bit of `(unsigned int)v` will be 0.

Now, for a negative `v` in the range from to -2<sup>N-1</sup> to -1 (this range is a superset of the negative ranges for the three possible representations of `int`), `(unsigned int)v` will be in the range from  2<sup>N</sup>+(-2<sup>N-1</sup>) to 2<sup>N</sup>+(-1), simplifying which we arrive at the range from 2<sup>N-1</sup> to 2<sup>N</sup>-1. Clearly, the most significant bit of this value will always be 1.

If you look carefully at all this math, you will see that the value of `(unsigned)v` looks exactly the same in binary as `v` in 2's complement representation:

...
`v` = -2: `(unsigned)v` = 2<sup>N</sup> - 2 = 111...110<sub>2</sub>
`v` = -1: `(unsigned)v` = 2<sup>N</sup> - 1 = 111...111<sub>2</sub>
`v` =  0: `(unsigned)v` =                 0 = 000...000<sub>2</sub>
`v` =  1: `(unsigned)v` =                 1 = 000...001<sub>2</sub>
...

So, there, the most significant bit of the value `(unsigned)v` is going to be 0 for `v`>=0 and 1 for `v`<0.

Now, let's get back to the sign-and-magnitude and one's complement representations. These two representations may allow two zeroes, a `+0` and a `-0`. But arithmetic computations do not visibly distinguish between `+0` and `-0`, it's still a `0`, whether you add it, subtract it, multiply it or compare it. You, as an observer, normally wouldn't see `+0` or `-0` or any difference from having one or the other.

Trying to observe and distinguish `+0` and `-0` is generally pointless and you should not normally expect or rely on the presence of two zeroes if you want to make your code portable.

`(unsigned int)v` won't tell you the difference between `v=+0` and `v=-0`, in both cases `(unsigned int)v` will be equivalent to `0u`.

So, with this method you won't be able to tell whether internally `v` is a `-0` or a `+0`, you won't extract v's sign bit this way for `v=-0`.

But again, you gain nothing of practical value from differentiating between the two zeroes and you don't want this differentiation in portable code.

So, with this I dare to declare the method for sign extraction presented in the question quite/very/pretty-much/etc portable in practice.

This method is an overkill, though. And `(int)v` in the original code is unnecessary as `v` is already an `int`.

This should be more than enough and easy to comprehend:

```
int sign = -(v < 0);
```

Comment: You don't receive a value that's 2's complement at all. The representation is undefined.

Comment: @Scrubbins From C99: For unsigned integer types other than `unsigned char`... If there are N value bits, each bit shall represent a different power of 2 between 1 and 2**(N-1), so that objects of that type shall be capable of representing values from 0 to 2**(N - 1) using a *pure binary representation*; this shall be known as the value representation.

Comment: @Scrubbins Moreover, conversion from `int` to `unsigned int` is well defined value-wise. So, there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: @Alexey and what does happen if the representation of int is excess-127 with 32 bits?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Show me such a machine in common use. Also note the wording: `quite portable`. Btw, it doesn't seem you can have excess-127 (if I understand what you mean by this) with 32 bits. That doesn't quite fit into the 3 possible representations of signed ints: sign-magnitude, two's complement, one's complement. There needs to be almost perfect symmetry in the range of signed integers (imperfect only for 2's complement case).

Answer (score 4):

It's not strictly portable, since it is theoretically possible that `int` and/or `unsigned int` have padding bits.

In a hypothetical implementation where `unsigned int` has padding bits, shifting right by `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT - 1` would produce undefined behaviour since then

```
sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT - 1 >= WIDTH
```

But for all implementations where `unsigned int` has no padding bits - and as far as I know that means all existing implementations - the code

```
int v;
int sign; // the sign of v ;
sign = -(int)((unsigned int)((int)v) >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1));
```

must set `sign` to `-1` if `v < 0` and to 0 if `v >= 0`. (Note - thanks to [Sander De Dycker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/822669/sander-de-dycker) for pointing it out - that if `int` has a negative zero, that would also produce `sign = 0`, since `-0 == 0`. If the implementation supports negative zeros and the sign for a negative zero should be `-1`, neither this shifting, nor the comparison `v < 0` would produce that, a direct inspection of the object representation would be required.)

The cast to `int` before the cast to `unsigned int` before the shift is entirely superfluous and does nothing.

It is - disregarding the hypothetical padding bits problem - portable because the conversion to unsigned integer types and the representation of unsigned integer types is prescribed by the standard.

Conversion to an unsigned integer type is reduction modulo `2^WIDTH`, where `WIDTH` is the number of value bits in the type, so that the result lies in the range 0 to `2^WIDTH - 1` inclusive.

Since without padding bits in `unsigned int` the size of the range of `int` cannot be larger than that of `unsigned int`, and the standard mandates (6.2.6.2) that signed integers are represented in one of

- sign and magnitude
- ones' complement
- two's complement

the smallest possible representable `int` value is `-2^(WIDTH-1)`. So a negative `int` of value `-k` is converted to `2^WIDTH - k >= 2^(WIDTH-1)` and thus has the most significant bit set.

A non-negative `int` value, on the other hand cannot be larger than `2^(WIDTH-1) - 1` and hence its value will be preserved by the conversion and the most significant bit will not be set.

So when the result of the conversion is shifted by `WIDTH - 1` bits to the right (again, we assume no padding bits in `unsigned int`, hence `WIDTH == sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT`), it will produce a 0 if the `int` value was non-negative, and a `1` if it was negative.

Comment: +1 for good wording and through explanation. Funny I didn't say anything wrong, meant the same thing as in your answer and got -1. :)

Comment: Yes, it's strange. I think your mistake was to say "you receive a value that is 2's complement bit representation of the value of the original" without elaborating, so people thought you said that `int`s were represented in two's complement. Took me a couple of seconds too to see what you meant.

Comment: Could be that, I clearly didn't imply physical representation.

Comment: apart from padding bits, there is also the possibility that the 'sign and magnitude' representation is used, in which case the sign bit might not be where you expect it. Furthermore, there is also the possibility of negative zeroes if the representation is not two's complement. Of course, the assumption of two's complement without padding bits is generally true (especially on modern hardware), but according to the letter of the standard, this is not guaranteed.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Good point about the negative zeros, if they exist, and should give sign `-1`, that fails indeed. For truly negative values, however, the location of the sign bit, and which representation of signed integers is chosen, is irrelevant. The conversion specified by the standard, and the "pure binary representation" requirement for unsigned (and non-negative values of signed) integer types guarantees that the resulting bit pattern of the conversion is the two's complement representation of the original value.

Comment: @Daniel : quite right - I overlooked the cast to `unsigned` which indeed takes care of any sign bit in an odd location.

Answer (score 1):

Nope its just excessive casting.  There is no need to cast it to an int.  It doesn't hurt however.

Edit: Its worth noting that it may be done like that so the type of v can be changed to something else or it may have once been another data type and after it was converted to an int the cast was never removed.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't. The Standard does not define the representation of integers, and therefore it's impossible to guarantee exactly what the result of that will be portably. The only way to get the sign of an integer is to do a comparison.